# this book is sold subject to the condition that... -- I don't quite understand the "is sold subject to" part

Tags: grammar

Example sentence:

> **This book is sold subject to the condition** that it shall not, by way of trade or otherwise, be lent, re-sold, hired out or otherwise circulated without the publisher’s prior consent in any form of binding or cover other than that in which it is published and without a similar condition including this condition being imposed on the subsequent purchaser.

I don't quite understand the grammar behind the ***is sold subject to*** part. Is ***subject to the condition that...*** used as some kind of adverbial construct? If so, then I believe I can ask the following question:

> *How is this book sold?*

And receive the following answer:

> *It is sold subject to the condition that you are not allowed to make copies of it and redistribute it.*

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102666/11482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means "This book is sold **on condition** that ___" in legalese.

Your understanding is correct.